# Flutter, get image as data back from c++ opencv

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, dart-ffi

I am really new to Flutter and C++. So I am struggling with this one. I want to do some transformation to an image through ffi->c++ (opencv). Here's my code on the Flutter side:

```
class Processvalue extends Struct {
  Pointer<Utf8> image;

  factory Processvalue.allocate(Pointer image) =>
      malloc<Processvalue>().ref
        ..image = image;
}
```

I am basically accepting a pointer back from C++ side. Then I call C++ native function like so:

```
...
final processImage = nativeEdgeDetection
        .lookup<NativeFunction<ProcessImageFunction>>("process_image")
        .asFunction<ProcessImageNativeFunction>();
...
```

On the C++ side, in the `process_image` function I am using the following:

```
...
Mat dst = Mat::zeros(maxHeight, maxWidth, CV_8UC1);
Mat transformation_matrix = getPerspectiveTransform(img_pts, dst_pts);
warpPerspective(img, dst, transformation_matrix, dst.size());
uchar * arr = dst.isContinuous()? dst.data: dst.clone().data;
```

Basically, I am sending image path from Flutter to C++ through ffi package. And in C++ grab the image from this file and create opencv Mat variable `dst`, which will hold the new transformed image. Then I convert this Mat variable to `uchar * arr`, which I am returning back to Flutter (Pointer to arr). However in Flutter I am not able to convert this back to image data (Uint8List for example).

I have seen people use `cv::imwrite(path, dst);` to save transformation directly to the same file. But for me I want to keep the original file and only want to get the new image **as data** back in Flutter and show it through `MemoryImage(...Uint8List variable...)`.

How do I send **image data** back to Flutter from C++? At the end I would like to have a `Uint8List`. Is `uchar * arr` even a good option for this?

I have tried the following but it gives me an `invalid image data` error:

```
int imageArrLength = _result.ref.image.length;
                       ^- Pointer back from C++
Uint8List image = _result.ref.image.cast<Uint8>().asTypedList(imageArrLength);
```

Comment: In what format is the image data returned? (PNG, JPEG, unencoded RGBA, etc.)

Comment: @ChristopherMoore JPG

Comment: Please hexdump both the data you're about to return on the C side and the data you have on the Dart side. Please confirm that you see the JPEG header in both. Should be an ASCII `JFIF` at the 5th byte.

Comment: Please also specify where you're getting the `invalid image data` error and provide a full error/stacktrace if applicable.

Comment: Hi @pewpewlasers, did you able to fix the problem?